# Install local package to satisfy a node module dependency?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

Say for example we have the following project structure:

**node_modules (myproject)**

```
myproject
|- module1
|- module2
```

and `module2` depends on `module1`:

**node_modules (module2)**

```
module2
|- module1
```

so the entire dependency structure is now:

```
myproject
|- module1
|- module2
   |- module1
```

---

Let's say I forked the git repo of `module1` and want to add a feature to it. How would I go about installing `module1` locally so that the new functionality of `module1` is exposed to both `module2` and `myproject`, all without publishing to an npm repository? I'm using npm 2.

For the sake of the argument, lets assume that the directory of the `module1` fork is named `module1-fork` and shares the parent directory of `myproject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use npm [link functionality](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)

`cd module1-fork
npm link
cd ../myproject
npm link module1
cd node_modules/module2
npm link module1`